# WinMgmts error on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, wmi

I have a VBS file that is failing on this line:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("WinMgmts:{authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}
\\myserver\root\MicrosoftIISv2")
```

with this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: The remote server machine does not
exist or is unavailable: 'GetObject'
```

where `myserver` is a Windows 2008 SP2 server.  I made sure WMI is running on the server.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you prepend the code with `On Error Resume Next` and append `WScript.Echo Err & " : " & Err.Description`

Try the code remotely.

Then, try the code locally on the server with `myserver` substituted with `.` - i.e.: local machine.  Run the code with and without local admin privs...

Comment: 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: When I run it locally with "." there is no error on that statement, but the next statment: objWMIService.Get("IIsApplicationPool.Name=myPool") gives me "SWbemServicesEx: Provider load failure"

Comment: Have a nose at <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961987.aspx>

Comment: ( Fixed link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb961987.aspx )